# capture both eyes in python opencv

Tags: python, opencv, detection, haar-classifier

I want to detect both eyes from image, but when I use Haar cascade it returns each eye separately. what should I do to crop both eyes together from the image?
here is my code:

```
image = cv2.imread('KA.AN1.39.tiff')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')
eye = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(image)
for (x,y,w,h) in eye:
    eye = image[y : y+h , x : x+w]
    cv2.imshow('eye', eye)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

thanks for your help

Comment: for eye in eyes ?

Answer (score 1):

```
for x,y,w,h in eye:
    roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    eyes = eyePair_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)   
    if len(eyes) == 0: return   
    for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
        eyes_roi = roi_color[ey: ey+eh, ex:ex + ew]
        #cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)

cv2.imwrite(outfile, eyes_roi)
```

Also see [Detection of eye pairs in Python OpenCV (Panoptigram)](https://crude2refined.wordpress.com/2014/05/17/detection-of-eye-pairs-in-python-opencv-panoptigram/)